# How to take only one entry from a table based on an offset to a date column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a requirement to get values from a table based on an offset conditions on a date column.
Say for eg: for the below attached table, if there is any dates that comes close within 15 days based on effectivedate column I should return only the first one.

[image: Table Content]

So my expected result would be as below:

Here for A1234 policy, it returns 6/18/16 entry and skipped 6/12/16 entry as the offset between these 2 dates is within 15 days and I took the latest one from the list.

[image]

Comment: What if there are a sequence of such dates?  You need to clarify the question -- Jan 1, Jan 10, Jan 20, Jan 30, Feb 10, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group rows together that are within 15 days of each other, then you have a variant of the gaps-and-islands problem.  I would recommend `lag()` and cumulative sum for this version:

```
select polno, min(effectivedate), max(expirationdate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_ed >= dateadd(day, -15, effectivedate)
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by polno order by effectivedate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(expirationdate) over (partition by polno order by effectivedate) as prev_ed
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by polno, grp;
```